# When to use an auto-increment key?

Tags: mysql

I've recently started to work on MySQL and while I've read some documentation on database structure, I cannot get my head around auto-increment keys and why using them.

I have been told:

- it's best to use a number instead of text as a primary key,
- it's best to use a key that doesn't have any business signification

Let's look at the situation below:

```
 tStores        tSales         tCustomers
----------    -----------    --------------
store_id       sale_id        customer_id
storeCode      store_id
               customer_id
```

First, I load some data in `tStores` for all the stores products can be sold. In our business, all stores have a 4 letters code to identify them. I could use this as a primary key, but based on the recommendations above I should use a store_id field that auto-increments?

The problem is, each time I insert something in `tSales`, I have to go back to `tStores` and do something like:

```
SELECT store_id from tStores WHERE storeCode = @myStoreCode;
```

Assuming I am loading hundreds of thousands rows in `tSales` for each store, would it not be more efficient to use the `storeCode` as primary key? 
What would be the most efficient way to deal with this?

Comment: What is wrong with `insert into tSales (sale_id, store_id) values (4, (select store_id from tStores where storeCode = "foo"));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use `storeCode` as the primary key, it will work if you can ensure it is unique. Then you will add a foreign key on your other tables to establish the relationship.

The benefit of auto increment index are:

- It is usually faster than any index on other column type
- It is usually recommended by some framework (such as Laravel in PHP)

Related to you structure I would comment on some points:

- You have mixed casing columns/tables. When working on MySQL, especially when used on different OS (Windows/Linux), I would always recommend to use lowercase names for both schemas, tables and columns.
- You added a prefix in front of `store_id` and `store_code`. This prefix is not necessary. Why not simply naming the columns `id` and `code`.
- The relationship on `tSales` should be named `tStores_id` instead to clearly indicate from which table and which column you are referring to.

Here the SQL code for this example:

```
CREATE SCHEMA `myshop` ;

CREATE TABLE `store`.`stores` (
  `code` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`));

CREATE TABLE `store`.`sales` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_code` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `store`.`customers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

ALTER TABLE `store`.`sales` 
ADD INDEX `fk_sales_customers_id_idx` (`customer_id` ASC) VISIBLE;

ALTER TABLE `store`.`sales` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sales_customers_id`
  FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`)
  REFERENCES `store`.`customers` (`id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `store`.`sales` 
ADD INDEX `fk_sales_stores_code_idx` (`store_code` ASC) VISIBLE;

ALTER TABLE `store`.`sales` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_sales_stores_code_id`
  FOREIGN KEY (`store_code`)
  REFERENCES `store`.`stores` (`code`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I think I'll go for `storeCode` as Primary Key then, but I'll make some tests to see the difference in timing when running my queries over a large set of data!